# How I can traverse the HTML tree using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, traversal

I think this question has been asked, but I not found anything.

From the `Document` element in Jsoup, how I can traverse for all elements in the HTML content?

I was reading the documentation and I was thinking about using the `childNodes()` method, but it only takes the nodes from one leval below (what I understand). I think I can use some recursion with this method, but I want to know if there is a more appropriate/native way to do this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From [`Document`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) (and any [`Node`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html) subclass), you can use the [`traverse(NodeVisitor)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#traverse%28org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor%29) method.

For example:

```
document.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {
    public void head(Node node, int depth) {
        System.out.println("Entering tag: " + node.nodeName());
    }
    public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
        System.out.println("Exiting tag: " + node.nodeName());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can select all elements of the document using * selector.

```
Elements elements = document.body().select("*");
```

2) For retrieve text of each individually using Element.ownText() method.

```
for (Element element : elements) {
  System.out.println(element.ownText());
}
```

3) For modify the text of each individually using Element.html(String strHtml). (clears any existing inner HTML in an element, and replaces it with parsed HTML.)

```
element.html(strHtml);
```

Hope this will help you.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
public class JsoupDepthFirst {

    private static String htmlTags(Document doc) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        htmlTags(doc.children(), sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void htmlTags(Elements elements, StringBuilder sb) {
        for(Element el:elements) {
            if(sb.length() > 0){
                sb.append(",");
            }
            sb.append(el.nodeName());
            htmlTags(el.children(), sb);
            sb.append(",").append(el.nodeName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        String s = "<html><head>this is head </head><body>this is body</body></html>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(s);
        System.out.println(htmlTags(doc));
    }
}
```